# Orphan properties in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am executing following Cypher query.

```
START n = node(*) 
MATCH n-[r?]-() 
DELETE n,r
```

Despite executing it, dashboard shows 140 nodes 50,000 properties and 75 relationships.

Question - Is the dashboard wrong or I have orphan nodes etc? Will the dashboard eventually show the right stats? I would have restarted the server but it is hosted on Azure and I am not quite sure how to restart it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dashboard doesn't actually show the number of nodes but the highest node ID assigned. Since you've deleted the nodes, that node ID will eventually be recycled and the dashboard would reflect it at some point.

To know if you really deleted everything, you can always execute

```
START n=node(*)
return count(n)
```